# How to adding PDF for Admin to view Orders

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have tried to add the option to view order through PDF in the admin panel but I am getting error which I do not know the reason for nor how to fix it.

This is what I did step by step. The issue is now that I have tried restart everything but I am still getting the error.

```
$ pip install weasyprint django-import-export
```

then I added it in the installed apps `'import_export',`
Here is the admin.py

```
def order_pdf(obj):
    return mark_safe('<a href="{}">PDF</a>'.format(reverse('orders:admin_order_pdf', args=[obj.id])))


order_pdf.short_description = 'Order PDF'

class OrderAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', order_pdf]
```

here is the views.py

```
@staff_member_required
def admin_order_pdf(request,order_id):
    Order = get_object_or_404(order,id=order_id)
    html = render_to_string('order/pdf.html',{'order':Order})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="order_{}.pdf"'.format(Order.id)
    # weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response,stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'css/pdf.css')])
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response,stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT)])

    return response
```

here is the url.py

```
    path('admin/order/(?P<order_id>\d+)/pdf/$', views.admin_order_pdf, name='admin_order_pdf')
```

Here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 272, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\Moustiques\urls.py", line 15, in <module>
    path('', include('core.urls', namespace='core')),
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A_K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\A_K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\core\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\core\views.py", line 6, in <module>
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    import weasyprint
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\__init__.py", line 440, in <module>
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 387, in check
    from .css import preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa isort:skip
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\css\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    from . import computed_values, media_queries
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\css\computed_values.py", line 18, in <module>
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    from .. import text
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\text.py", line 14, in <module>
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    cairo = dlopen(
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 45, in dlopen
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
OSError: no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

  File "C:\Users\A_K\Desktop\Project 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 571, in url_patterns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

weasyprint or django-import-export is dependent on libcairo is a shared library. Some python packages are automatically compiled with all the dependencies, but this is not the case. If you don't want to figure out how to install libcairo yourself, I would suggest that you use Anaconda, which does a good job at installing dependencies on Windows.

https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

I verified that Anaconda has the cairocffi package, which is the python wrapper around the libcairo that triggers the error.

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cairocffi